# Issue with marginfigure in twocolumn document

Tags: margins, multicol, marginpar, scrbook

I have a `twocolumn` document with a large `marginpar` on right side. When I am including `marginfigure` it works correctly if it is in the right column. But if it is in the left column, the margin figure is pushed in the left side margin `left` and is not visible completely. How can I force the marginfigure to be in the `marginpar` from both the columns? Same issue is with the `marginnote` and `sidenote` as well.

I tried looking at a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108981/marginpar-on-a-fixed-side-of-two-column-double-sided-memoir-document/473559?noredirect=1#comment1599517_473559) with memoir class but no solution there.

[image: marginfigure pushed to left margin]

[image: correct marginfigure]

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,a4paper,landscape,twoside=semi]{scrbook}
\setlength{\columnsep}{25pt}
\usepackage{geometry} 



\geometry{top=15mm,bottom=25mm, textheight=195mm, headsep=5mm, left=15mm, right=85mm, textwidth=100mm, marginpar=70mm,marginparsep=5mm}                   

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}



\usepackage{sidenotes}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}

\begin{marginfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ske.jpg}
\caption{a figure}
\end{marginfigure}

\lipsum


\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{marginfigure}%[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ske.jpg}
\caption{a figure}
\end{marginfigure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal, but it might help you out.
With the textpos package.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,a4paper,landscape,twoside=semi]{scrbook}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{25pt}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641760/issue-with-marginfigure-in-twocolumn-document/641859#641859
    \usepackage{geometry} 
    \geometry{top=15mm,bottom=25mm, textheight=195mm, headsep=5mm, left=15mm, right=85mm, textwidth=100mm, marginpar=70mm,marginparsep=5mm}                   
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{sidenotes}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %\usepackage[absolute,showboxes]{textpos}<--- for the test
    \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

    \textblockorigin{217mm}{15mm}%217<---297mm-70mm-10mm?
    \newcommand{\placemarge}[3]{%
    % 3.8 per test
        \begin{textblock}{3.8}(0,#3)% postion absolue
            \centering
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[width=70mm]{#1}
                \caption{#2}             
            \end{figure}
    \end{textblock}
    }

    \begin{document}
    \placemarge{example-image-a.jpg}{a figure A}{0} 
    \lipsum
    \placemarge{example-image-b.jpg}{a figure B}{1}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \placemarge{example-image-c.jpg}{a figure C}{6} 
    \end{document}
```

[image]